# $S_1 \subset S_2$. To show, $Span(S_1) \subset Span(S_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $S_{1} \subset S_{2}$, then $Span(S_{1}) \subset Span(S_{2})$

Approach: Suppose $S_{1} \subset S_{2}$

Let $x \in S_{1}$, then by definition of a subset, $x \in S_{2}$

All possible linear combinations of $x$ are $cx$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$

So $cx \in Span(S_{1})$

But $x$ is also in $S_{2}$, therefore $Span(S_{2})$ contains all linear combinations of $x$ as well.

So $cx \in Span(S_{2})$

We have $cx \in Span(S_{1})$, then $cx \in Span({S2})$  $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$

We have shown: if $S_{1} \subset S_{2} \Rightarrow Span(S_{1}) \subset Span(S_{2})$

Is my approach to the question correct? If so, is this enough to answer the question or have I missed something?

Comment: It's not true that "all possible linear combinations of $x$ are $cx$ with $x \in \mathbb R$". You have to consider all finite sums of such elements.

Comment: How do I consider all finite sums?

Comment: Remind yourself: How do the elements of $\operatorname{Span}(S_1)$ look like? Once you know that, you have to show that each such element is in $\operatorname{Span}(S_2)$ - which is pretty much immediate.

Comment: I was thinking about starting with: Let $ \overrightarrow v \in Span(S_{1})$, then $ \overrightarrow v$ is all possible linear combinations of vectors pertaining to $S_{1}$ such that: $ \overrightarrow v= \sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i} \overrightarrow w_{i}$ with $c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ \overrightarrow w_{i} \in S_{1}$. But $S_{1} \subset S_{2}$ so $w_{i} \in S_{2}$ as well. So $ \overrightarrow v$ is also all possible linear combinations of vectors pertaining to $S_{2}$. Would that be enough?

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. However, $\overrightarrow v$ is not **all** possible linear combinations of elements in $S_1$, but **a** linear combination of such elements.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your input and help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd also like to suggest that you accept Henning's answer or provide your own, if you prefer that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not a valid approach.

In order to show that $\mathit{Span}(S_1)\subseteq \mathit{Span}(S_2)$ you need to start with an *arbitrary* element of $\mathit{Span}(S_1)$ and show that it is also an element of $\mathit{Span}(S_2)$.

You have shown this only for elements of $\mathit{Span}(S_1)$ that *happen to have* the form $cx$ for some $c$ and and $x\in S_1$, but there will generally be elements of $\mathit{Span}(S_1)$ that do not have this simple form.